# How can I observe two LiveData and use results together. How to implement MediatorLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I got to live data observer and one function that need results from both observers. How to make this function calls when both observers receives data? Not code looks like this

```
firstViewModel.dataOne.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        secondViewModel.dataTwo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { dataTwoResult ->
            setAssociateInfo(dataTwoResult, it) // <--- send two parameters from to observers together
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can store the data as a list or as an object

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu I think mediatorLiveData might work but still working on implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work (all code untested but *should* work fine) :

```
val a : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(1)
val b : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("B")

val c : MediatorLiveData<Pair<Int?, String?>> = MediatorLiveData<Pair<Int?, String?>>().apply {
    addSource(a) { value = Pair(it, b.value) }
    addSource(b) { value = Pair(a.value, it) }
}

c.observe(lco, Observer {  })
```

This will work akin to combine latest.

As a simple extension function :

```
fun <T, S> LiveData<T?>.combineWith(other: LiveData<S?>): LiveData<Pair<T?, S?>> =
    MediatorLiveData<Pair<T?, S?>>().apply {
        addSource(this@combineWith) { value = Pair(it, other.value) }
        addSource(other) { value = Pair(this@combineWith.value, it) }
    }
```

Usage :

```
firstViewModel.dataOne.combineWith(secondViewModel.dataTwo)
              .observe(viewLifecycowner, Observer { latestPairResult ->  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my approach you can store the data inside data class instead of creating separate variable and observe them
Like

```
//data class
//you can declare the data type to be stored
data class Datas(val data0: String , val data1: String)
//
//...
//inside view model
private val _datas = MutableLiveData<Datas> ()
val datas: LiveData = _datas

init {
    viewmodelscope.launch {
         //store the changes here
        val value = Datas("value1","value2")
        _datas.value = value
   }
}
```

And finally you can observe it like

```
myviewmode.datas.observe(lifecycle){
      setAssociateInfo(it.data0, it.data1)
}
```

Comment: But how to get access to value1 and value2 from two different observers?

Comment: No need to create 2 different observers you can get 2 values or more from 1 Observer

Comment: No. The problem here is that I already got two observers and I need to combine values from there in one

Comment: Ah so it's mandatory to create 2 Observer?

Comment: yes I already have them and listen in activity. I need to merge two values from there and call function

Comment: Ah as I see , you need to use MediatorLiveData

Comment: yes. just trying to implement. no success so far